# PostgreSQL union a variable of type array to the result set of a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to union a to union a variable to a select statement in PostgreSQL? I have a recursive function at the moment that in essence does this:

```
create or replace function call_recurrsive_function(ids bigint[])
.
.
select id from x where y
union call_recurrsive_function(select id from x where y)
.
```

I've recently made some changes that increase the complexity of the select by a lot, and to increase performance I'd like to run that query only once per function call and do something like

```
var = select id from x where y 
union call_recurrsive_function(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a CTE (Common Table Expression). For example:

```
with
r as (
  select id from x where y
)
select *
from (
  select id from r
  union call_recurrsive_function(select id from r)
) x
```